# RichTextbox SelectionStart returns wrong index

Tags: .net, wpf, text, richtextbox

I need to show the user, like in notepad.exe, the selection start and length of his text on cursor.

Selection length is no problem because Richtextbox supports the Selection Property with Start and End.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getoffsettoposition.aspx

But the startindex of my RichTexbox is always `2` instead of `0` if I set the cursor on first position of the document.
If I CLEAR the complete text it is on `0`. But if I press `SPACE` and then `BACKSPACE` the textbox is empty but the counter of StartIndex is on `2`

Any idea?

[image: TB HyperTerminal Win7]

---

*** EDIT  *** FIRST SOLUTION

Ok, thats a working solution of mine. But I think there is a better way to do it.

```
''' <summary>
    ''' Get the position of the cursor. Ignores all formatting characters like ENTER and PARAGRAPH. Just counts the visible characters.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="rtb">The richtextbox the value should be determined</param>
    ''' <returns>Index value of the cursor. 0 is at the first position. After position is behind characters "123" it would return the index 3.</returns>
    ''' <remarks>Watch out for performance, Use this methode in separated. Timo Böhme, 2012</remarks>
    Private Function GetPositionOfCursor(ByVal rtb As RichTextBox) As Integer
        Dim contentStart As TextPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart
        Dim res As Integer = 0
        Dim CursorIndex As Integer = contentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(rtb.CaretPosition)
        Dim j As Integer = 0

        Do
            If j > CursorIndex Then Exit Do
            If contentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward) Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf contentStart.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Backward) = TextPointerContext.Text Then
                res += 1
            End If

            contentStart = contentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward)
            j += 1
        Loop

        Return res
    End Function
```

Comment: The RichTextBox automatically creates a Paragraph and a Run (or something similar), hence the non-zero index. The cursor is not at the start but in the first run in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks again H.B. for your very quick response. Do you have any solution?

Comment: No, otherwise i would have posted an answer.

Comment: Try to use `GetPointerContext` method on `TextPointer` class object to validate if its value is `TextPointerContext.Text`. You can find also some more information about `RichTextBox` selection here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454440/select-range-of-text-in-wpf-richtextbox-flowdocument-programmatically. It's about selecting text rather than checking the selection, but it can be helpful for you (if you want to get text selection start and end positions).

If you want more information please give us more details on what do you want this part of your code to do.

Comment: Thanks Lucas for your answer. The way of searching for characters is not nice but works. I am not satisfied with my solution (on top) and will wait. Perhaps someone knows how to do it with RTB internals.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this is a real answer to your question, but I use this simple trick to retrieve the cursor index related tot the text:

`TextRange range = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, CaretPosition);`
`int n = range.Text.Length;`

I'm working on an editor based on the WPF richtextbox. Since real time formatting (like highlighting keywords and such) is really slow I create a new document in another thread. In this thread the text gets formatted in appropiate runs, rather than formatting them as a part of the richtextbox's paragraph. Once finished the original one is replaced by the new one. Works really nice and incredible fast (compared to the MS way at least).

I hope this give you some inspiration and/or ideas.