# DataTrigger not working (LineCount always -1)

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

The datatrigger below is not working. Any idea why not?
I checked in code behind that the LineCount in two situations is 1 respectively 4.
But when I change the Value to "-1" the trigger is working.
So why is the LineCount always -1?

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextInfo" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Information" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="OrangeRed">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineCount, ElementName=TextInfo}" Value="4">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineCount, ElementName=TextInfo}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="PowderBlue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I just saw in MSDN TextBox.LineCount Property: you cannot set this property in xaml (framework 3.5).

Comment: In code via `this.TextInfo.TextChanged += TextInfo_TextChanged;` it works, I guess that's somewhat easier then creating the attached dependency property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick decompile of the `TextBox` code shows that `LineCount` is not a `DependencyProperty`. So when the value is updated it will not update your trigger.

This is `LineCount` property from the `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` class in C#. You can see here that there is not `DependencyProperty` backing the property.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public int LineCount
{
  get
  {
    if (this.RenderScope == null)
      return -1;
    else
      return this.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(this.TextContainer.SymbolCount) + 1;
  }
}
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870365/multiline-textbox-display-current-line-character-index-in-statusbar) as a decent solution for creating an attached property that will observe when the text in the `TextBox` is modified, and give the current line position. You can change your binding to listen for the attached property.

Comment: "A quick decompile of the TextBox code" - how do you do that?

Comment: @Gerard There are several applications that will allow you to decompile assemblies. A free, and pretty decent one is [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [`TextBox.LineCount` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN, we can see that it is *not* a `DependencyProperty`. Furthermore, as the `TextBox` class does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, I can only imagine that the value of this property will never update for you in a `Binding` and can only be used in code.

The only way that I can see you using this property is if you create an `Attached Property` to access it and expose the updated value.

Comment: How do you see in MSDN that it is not a DependencyProperty?

Comment: When a property is a `DependencyProperty`, the property page on MSDN will have a 'Dependency Property Information' section... compare the `TextBox.LineCount` Property page with the `TextBox.Text` Property page.

Comment: Thyvm, I accepted Kevin DeLorey's answer to give him a quick start ;)

Comment: Not a problem at all my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `ElementName`, use `RelativeSource`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="4">
```

Comment: This makes no difference, it works also, but again LineCount is always -1.

Answer (score 0):

The **LineCount** property of a **TextBox** can be used to retrieve the current number of lines of text in a **TextBox**.  If the **text wraps** to multiple lines, this property will reflect the visible number of wrapped lines that the user sees.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextInfo" Text="Information" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="OrangeRed" **TextWrapping="Wrap"**>
    <TextBox.Style>
     ....
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```